# SaveAs corrupts file

Tags: excel, vba, save-as

I have written a macro that saves a file as `finished file` then opens that file to run another macro.

There are no issues until I try to run this code on another computer.

Here is where the code breaks.

```
' Note I have tried several file formats.
ocd_wb.SaveAs Filename:="finished file", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook

Set re_wb = Workbooks.Open("finished file")
```

On my coworker's PC it errors and when I check the file it is corrupt.

Everything I check on the net says to save as various file types. `(52, xlOpenXMLWorkbook, xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled)`. None of which work. Note that all of those formats work on my PC.

Update: We both have Office 2010 so it is not a version issue.

Comment: I think I know the problem, does your colleague have show extension enabled? Perhaps it is shown in excel as "finished file.xlsm"

Comment: @Sgdva I will need to check. Why would that affect how excel saves files? It should not matter if the extension is visible to the user or not.

Comment: Are there any errors? Anything like `Application.DisplayAlerts` disabled?

Comment: It does since the `Workbooks.Open` method refers to the window title too; if Windows have extensions enabled it'll show as "Book.xls" instead of "Book" in the Excel interface, hence the error